# Plugin framework in C++ with

Tags: c++, plugins, boost, frameworks, template-meta-programming

I'm designing (brainstorming) a C++ plugin framework for an extensible architecture.
Each plugin registers an interface, which is implemented by the plugin itself.
Such framework may be running on relatively capable embedded devices (e.g. Atom/ARM) so I can use STL and Boost.

At the moment I've managed to write a similar framework, in which interfaces are known in advance and plugins (loaded from dynamic libraries) register the objects implementing them. Those objects are instantiated as needed by their factory methods, and methods are called correctly.

Now I want to make it more flexible, having plugins register new interfaces (not just implementing the existing ones) thus extending the API available to the framework users.

I thought of using a std::map<std::string, FunctionPtr>, which is also mentioned by several articles and stackoverflow replies I've read. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to capture the case of different method interfaces.

I feel it might have something to do with template metaprogramming, or traits perhaps, but I can't figure out how it should work exactly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at XPCOM which solves these problems for you - by sortof re-implementing COM.

You have the issue of not knowing what interface the plugin provides to your application, so you need a way for the developer to access it, without the compiler knowing what it is (though, if you supply a header file, then suddenly you do know what it is and you can compile it without any need for plugin unknown-interface fanciness)

so, you're going to have to rely on runtime determinism of the interface, that roughly requires you to define the interface in some way so that the framework can call arbitrary methods on it, and I think the only realistic way you can do that is to define each interface as a set of function pointers that are loaded individually and then stored in data for the user to call. And that pretty much means a map of function pointers to names. It also means you can only user compiler niceties (such as overloading) by making the function names unique. The compiler does this for you by 'mangling' all functions to unique, coded names.

[Type Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/background.html) will help you wrap your imported functions in your framework, so you can inspect them and create classes that work with any imported type, but it isn't going to solve the main problem of importing arbitrary functions.

Possibly one approach that you'll want to read is [Metaclasses and Reflection](http://www.vollmann.com/en/pubs/meta/meta/meta.html) by Vollmann. This was referenced by the C++ standard body, though I don't know if it will become part of a future spec. Alternatively you can look at [Boost.Extension](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/boost_extension/introduction.html)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try type traits for now, and I'll have a look at Boost.Extension as well.
Vollmann's article is really interesting, but I'm quite concerned about how 'safe' that solution is: It looks like encapsulation is a bit screwed up :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the first thing you need check is COM.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that can be done with templates, can be done without, though perhaps in a much less convenient way, by writing "template instances" by hand.

If your framework was compiled without seeing a declaration of `class MyNewShinyInterface`, it cannot store pointers of type `MyNewShinyInterface *`, and cannot return them to the framework users. No amount of template wizardry can change that. The framework can only store an pass around pointers to some base class. The users will have to do a `dynamic_cast` to retrieve the correctly typed pointer.

The same is true about function pointers, only functions have no base classes and one will have to do the error-prone `reinterpret_cast` to retrieve the right type. (This is just another reason to prefer proper objects over function pointers.)